# how to terminate server on watchman rebuild

Tags: watchman

I have a simple watch target in my Makefile

```
watch:
  watchman-make -p '**/*.go' -t run
```

target `run` starts a web server and binds to a port. Upon file change, `run` is executed, but get the error.

```
bind: address already in use
```

this is because, the web server started previously is not terminated.
I see few threads related to this, but doesn't give a solution.

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/246
https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/447

Is this possible with watchman to terminate the server and release the port, before each build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not really directly controllable with watchman since it doesn't know anything about your server since it sounds like you're forking it off at the end of the build, but should be pretty simple: have your `run` target be responsible for tearing down the old server instance.

For example, in your Makefile:

```
run: build
      ./stop-running-server
      ./start-server
```

How you implement `stop-running-server` is up to you.  A couple of common techniques you could try are listed below:

- `pkill` to kill processes whose name matches that of your server
- Have your server write out its process id to a file and then you can `kill $(cat pidfile)` in the implementation of `stop-running-server`